# Can saliva under the dental crown cause problems in the long term?

Tags: dentistry

I recently learned that saliva contains hundreds of different kinds of bacteria (e.g. see [here](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4764907/)). Recalling that I was salivating profusely prior to a dentist crown being glued onto my tooth, I wonder
whether the saliva under the crown can cause problems in the long term.

In my research, most sources concerned the possible weakening of adhesive due to saliva (e.g. [here](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.5066497)). Some (e.g. [this](http://www.preferreddentalcenter.com/what-happens-to-the-tooth-under-a-dental-crown/)) touch on the topic, but do not give a clear answer.

Comment: This question is borderline with regard to asking for personal medical advice, which is strictly off topic here. You seem to be asking us to judge your dentist's decisions, which would be personal medical advice. But more importantly, it lacks prior research, which is required here. Does the adhesive contain antibacterial agents? I don't know. Did you try to find out? We don't require that you know the answer, but we do require that you make an attempt to find out.

Comment: @CareyGregory Thank you. I re-wrote the question.